# ExpressJS: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to add a validation method to my ExpressJS app, however it does not quite seem to work out... I can currently change the username, however if it has an empty String, the app crashes, although it is supposing to send an error. Any suggestions?

```
var validatePresenceOf = function(val, func) {
    if (typeof val === 'undefined' || val.length < 1) {
        res.json({
            errors: {
                userName: "Your name can't be blank"
            }
        });
    } else {
        return func;
    }
};

validatePresenceOf(req.body.userName, User.findByIdAndUpdate( currentUser._id, {
    local: {
        name                : req.body.userName
    }
}, function (err, user) {

    if (err) throw err;

    res.json({
        user : user
    });
}));
```

Comment: Your error should have a stack trace that has a reference to your code. Track down that line number and edit it into your question. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) covers the headers problem very thoroughly if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Express gives error when setHeader method called twice. Maybe you forgot or didn't use the "return" when validation method gives the error! Please check this. I'm believing [express validator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-validator) is better solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `User.findByIdAndUpdate()` immediately before validation check.

This one can temporarily fix your issue:

```
var validatePresenceOf = function(val, func) {
    if (typeof val === 'undefined' || val.length < 1) {
        res.json({
            errors: {
                userName: "Your name can't be blank"
            }
        });
    } else {
        func();
    }
};

validatePresenceOf(req.body.userName, function() {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate( currentUser._id, {
        local: {
            name: req.body.userName
        }
    }, function (err, user) {

        if (err) throw err;

        res.json({
            user : user
        });
    });
});
```

However, I would recommend using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) as a best practice for request validation.